# Check DATE format in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have below SELECT query in a procedure. I need to add another validation check for SUBMTD_SRVC_DATE column. If the value of SUBMTD_SRVC_DATE is in any format other than 'MMDDYYYY', then I need to populate '00000000'. Suppose, if SUBMTD_SRVC_DATE = '100515', then I need to automatically populate '00000000'.

Could anyone please on that. Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN SMS.SRVC_UNITS IS NULL OR SMS.SRVC_UNITS = -8888 OR SMS.SRVC_UNITS = -9999 THEN '0000000' ELSE LPAD( SMS.SRVC_UNITS , 7 , '0') END
                    || CASE WHEN ( SMS.SUBMTD_SRVC_DATE IS NULL OR UPPER(SMS.SUBMTD_SRVC_DATE) = 'NOT AVAILABLE') THEN '00000000' ELSE SMS.SUBMTD_SRVC_DATE END  AS FILE_VAL
FROM SUBMTD_MED_SRVC SMS
```

Comment: What should the check be? Check the length of the string? Is it always a numeric string? Does it always represent a date, maybe in different format, or can it be whatever value? For example, could a string like '02312017' exist in your data? Please try to better describe what you know on the starting data

Comment: is there anything that determines what constitutes a valid year? Anything after 1900?

Comment: @Aleksej : The input data type is varchar2(254). I mean to say that the input value should be returned back only when the input is in correct format of MMDDYYYY. Eg. 01222016. Otherwise, it should return '00000000'.

Comment: The question is what situations you may need to handle. If you have some assumptions on the input data, maybe some SQL logic could be enough, while if you can't say a thing about that, I believe you should consider the function approach as suggested.

Comment: As I have mentioned, the SQL logic which I require is: The input value should be returned back only when the input is in correct format of MMDDYYYY. Eg. 01222016. Otherwise, it should return '00000000'. I don't prefer to use Functions concept in my project since it is not recommended. Is there any other approach?

Comment: Of course, the simple way of doing this would be to change the datatype of the column to be DATE!

Comment: Again, what can you have in your data? Can you have whatever value, say 'XXXX855FFF'? Can you assume thah te strings always represent a date, but maybe with the wrong format? Can you make assumptions on your data? If so, which ones?

Answer (score 2):

Create a user-defined function and try to parse the date; if there are any exceptions then capture them and return your default string.

```
CREATE FUNCTION check_Date (
  datestring    VARCHAR2,
  format_mask   VARCHAR2 := 'FXMMDDYYYY',
  default_value VARCHAR2 := '00000000'
) RETURN VARCHAR2 DETERMINISTIC
IS
  INVALID_DATE EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT( INVALID_DATE, -20001 );

  p_date DATE;
BEGIN
  IF datestring IS NULL THEN
    RAISE INVALID_DATE;
  END IF;

  p_date := TO_DATE( datestring, format_mask );

  RETURN datestring;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RETURN default_value;
END check_Date;
/
```

**Alternative**:

```
SELECT CASE
       WHEN NOT REGEXP_LIKE( datestring, '^(0[1-9]|1[12])(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\d{4}$' )
       THEN '00000000'
       WHEN TO_CHAR(
              ADD_MONTHS(
                TRUNC( TO_DATE( SUBSTR( datestring, 5 ), 'YYYY' ), 'YYYY' ),
                TO_NUMBER( SUBSTR( datestring, 1, 2 ) ) - 1
              )
              + TO_NUMBER( SUBSTR( datestring, 3, 2 ) ) - 1,
              'MMDDYYYY'
            )
            <> datestring
       THEN '00000000'
       ELSE datestring
       END
FROM   your_table
```

Comment: Thanks.. Is there any approach other than using functions? My client doesn't want to use functions for this functionality. Is there any way to embed the required functionality in the SELECT query itself?

Comment: @prabuR Updated with an SQL solution but the function is much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

OP asked for a solution without functions, so I post my approach which uses a "with function" inside SQL, hope that's allowed by client:

```
with function fix_date(p_date_string varchar2) return varchar2
as
    v_date date;
begin
    v_date := TO_DATE( p_date_string, 'FXMMDDYYYY' );
    return p_date_string;
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RETURN '00000000';
end;
select 
    date_string,
    fix_date(date_string) fixed_date 
from (
    select '01012021' date_string from dual union all
    select '01xx2021' from dual union all
    select '13012021' from dual
);
/
```

Comment: I’m glad you posted this answer because I learned something, but the question is tagged 11g, and a quick Google indicates `with function` was introduced in 12c.

Answer (score 0):

One option might be to create a function that attempts to use `TO_DATE` to cast the input you're receiving into a a real `DATE`. If it succeeds, you know your date is valid, and return the original string, if it fails and throws an exception, you catch the exception and return `'000000'`:

```
create or replace function validate_date_string (
     p_date_string varchar2
)
return varchar2
is
l_date date;
l_date_string varchar2(8);
begin
    l_date_string := p_date_string;
    begin
        l_date := to_date (p_date_string, 'MMDDYYYY');
    exception
        when others then l_date_string := '000000'; 
    end;
    return l_date_string;
end;
/
```

Comment: `VARCHAR2(6)` will not fit an 8 character string.

Comment: Also the `MMDDYYYY` format mask will parse `100515` as 5th October 0015AD without throwing an exception - the OP stated that this should return `00000000`.

Comment: very true, a simple conditional statement could check if the string is the appropriate length though, this was more of a starter for ten than a complete solution!