# SQL : Checking format of column whose value is 'Date' but type is 'String'

Tags: sql, oracle, etl

I am running a ETL job which is failing due to data quality issues.
In my source, my date column is in String format and I am converting it to a `TIMESTAMP` using `to_timestamp()` method while storing it into target.

This job is failing when one date value(in String format) comes as `2016-06-` instead of `2016-11-10 06:07:48.633`. Due to the incorrect value, I can't convert it to a timestamp and my whole job fails.

How do I apply a format check in a generic way to verify that date(in String data type) is in correct format before converting it to timestamp?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/44018443/1509264 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/37659643/1509264

Comment: The real question: why are you storing timestamps in a `VARCHAR` column?

Comment: I agree to it completely but it is not in my control and I can't change it

Answer (score 1):

You could use Isdate() function to check if a string is date or not.

Use this function at filter level and filter the invalid dates and load the rest.